# Default username for CAS login screen from request parameter (query string)

Tags: cas, jasig

We are using JASIG CAS 3.5.2 and one requirement is to fill the username field from a link (query string).

Is there a standard way to do this? We would like the user to be able to override this default.

Many thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find built in support so since we were using the "overlay" customisation method anyway I added:

```
<c:if test="${commandName == 'credentials' && empty credentials.username}">
    <c:set target="${credentials}" property="username" value="${param.netid}" />
</c:if>
```

Just after the spring form element in casLoginView.jsp

NB In 4.0.x it gets renamed to "credential" so needs to be: